# Prevent gradle.properties expansion

Tags: java, spring, gradle, application.properties, gradle.properties

Im new in Gradle enviroment and I'm developing a Spring Application with property expansion in `application.properties` file, like:`server.port = $ {app_server_port}`

Everything is working OK, when I build with `gradle build` command, Gradle takes the file`~ / .gradle / gradle.properties` and expand variables into the builded `application.properties` file.

My question is:

- How can you prevent that property expansion?
- There is any command line argument in `gradle build` that will make it to ignore`~ / .gradle / gradle.properties` and build the source with the original values?
- There is something like `gradle build --skip-global-settings`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your build script like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def props = new Properties()
file("local.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it) }

processResources {
  if (project.hasProperty('expand'))
    expand(props)
}
```

Now if you build with `gradlew build -Pexpand` property expansion will be done with values from `local.properties`.

If you build with `gradlew build` no property expansion will take place.

---

As a note, I would recommend to not put project specific properties into `~ / .gradle / gradle.properties`, since this file is shared between all the projects that you build on your machine.

Comment: Thanks [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5646962/thomas-kl%c3%a4ger) it works like a charm